# Magento MSI Stock Status

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am noticing in Magento MSI on 2.4.3 that if default source is at quantity 0 item is_in_stock status goes to out of stock irrelevant of whether the other product sources have saleable quantity thats purchasable on front end still.

I have 3rd part extensions that rely on the is/out of stock status. This is no longer accurate when using MSI as if default value falls below 1 product stock status moving to out of stock. Is this correct functioning?

[image]